# Struct must outlive member reference

Tags: rust

I'm not sure how to properly title this post. I'm fairly new to Rust and trying to compile a program following this simple structure, but it seems to be incorrect, and I'm not sure why.

```
struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn do_thing(&self) { println!("Ha, do nothing!") }
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(b: &Bar) -> Foo { Foo { bar: b } }
    fn get_bar(&self) -> &Bar { self.bar }
}

fn main() {
    let b = Bar;
    let b_ref = {
        let f = Foo::new(&b);
        f.get_bar()
    };
    b_ref.do_thing();
}
```

The compiler error here claims that `f` does not live long enough. It shouldn't matter how long `f` lives though -- `b_ref` is valid for as long as `b` is, and I thought that references were `Copy` so that we wouldn't have to worry about the actual reference in `f`. Is this relevant?

Part of me feels like I need to specify the lifetime of the `&Bar` being returned from `get_bar`, but I don't know how to tie that into the lifetime of the `Foo` struct?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that the reference you are returning is tied to the lifetime `'a` and not the lifetime of self that compiler will infer for you:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(b: &Bar) -> Foo { Foo { bar: b } }
    fn get_bar(&self) -> &'a Bar { self.bar }
}
```

This is equivalent to the original code:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(b: &Bar) -> Foo { Foo { bar: b } }
    fn get_bar<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b Bar { self.bar }
}
```

> Part of me feel like I should need to specify the lifetime of the &Bar
>   being returned from get_bar, but I don't know how to tie that into the
>   lifetime of the Foo struct?

The lifetime of `Foo` does not matter at all in this case.